# How do I convert timestamp value retrieved from Firestore to Date()?

Tags: swift, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm relatively new to swift. Tried reviewing the docs but they aren't very helpful in that they are very brief and don't really explain well.

I mean to do a time check from FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp() and convert it to a Date() object.

I have managed to pull the time from Firestore as such:

```
func getTime() {

    let time = FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp()
    print(time)

    let RequestedDate = time.dateValue()
    print(RequestedDate)
}
```

which prints:

```
<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1586953390 nanoseconds=137923002>
2020-04-15 12:23:10 +0000
```

How do I convert said time & date to ***2020-04-15 12:23:10 +0000*** to Date() ?

Comment: there is a firestore toDate() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dateValue()` already returns a `Date` object. `2020-04-15 12:23:10 +0000` is just the `String` representation of that `Date` in your local timezone.